# Unable to boot from USB on Windows after removing dual booted linux

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, windows-10

I had previously installed elementary OS on my windows laptop and was trying to install normal ubuntu alongside it, but I kept having the issue of not being able to boot from the USB with the ubuntu ISO on it. I figured the issue was related to the elementary OS install so I removed that, but messed up the remove so I ended up having to manually boot into windows from the grub command line and then use the windows recovery CMD to remove the /efi/Boot/ubuntu folder to allow it to properly boot into windows.

Now I would like to install ubuntu, and no matter what I do I cannot get it to boot from the USB.

If I use the windows advanced options and select boot from disk the screen goes dark, but then the toshiba logo pops up, then the screen goes blank, then the logo pops up again and it boots into windows.

I'm not really sure what to do about this and would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB? and have you changed the boot priority to USB disk?

Comment: I created it with the 16.04 iso using rufus, and I currently have it set to boot from USB first.

Comment: Try creating USB with [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately the outcome was the same

Answer (score 0):

You might try booting into bios and give preference to usb in the boot menu to boot first, save and exit, see if it helps.

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunately it does not work. It seems like it tries to boot from it, and then gives up and boots from the hard drive, but I am not sure

Comment: What is the key to invoke "boot option" in your machine, F8 or F9 or F10 or ..., try to invoke "boot option" at system start, not going to the bios and try to boot from usb from the "boot option" and also give us the success or failure feedback.

Comment: I can access the boot menu by pressing f12, but I get the same outcome.